# Compiling my code into a .JAR using Terminal

Tags: java, jar, terminal, javac

Good Day,

I tried asking questions earlier but none of them could be answered as I failed to provide information. I will now list my problem below.

I have a Java Project with the following structure:
Lib has various jar libraries

[image]

Basically, I want this thing to be generated into a .jar file. Sure I could go into Eclipse, hit create Runnable .Jar file and move on. But I really want to know how this is done in terminal!

Hence I tried this

```
javac -cp .:lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:lib/jetty-all-8.1.9.v20130131.jar:lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar -d bin src/*.java
```

to compile it into .java files. it seemed to throw no errors and worked fine. As you can see three .jar files are included.

Then I tried to make a .jar file

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt bin/*.class
```

This generated a 4KB file that doesnt run at all. First of "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute". First of all, the eclipse compiled version was 2MB. This is 4KB. I can't understand why it isn't being compiled properly!

Manifest:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
>
> Created-By: 16.3-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
>
> Main-Class: Main
>
> Class-Path: lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar lib/jetty-all-8.1.9.v20130131.jar lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Please Help!

Comment: What is inside your Manifest?

Comment: Why don't you use eclipse to create the JAR?

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 16.3-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar lib/jetty-all-8.1.9.v20130131.jar lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Comment: the problem is with the Main-Class path i think. I have 0 IDEA what to put there..

Comment: Can you edit your question with it, it's very difficult to read here.

Comment: i have done so please see

Comment: It appears to be correct, the error says "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute", are you sure you are using the right file? Are you in the correct directory when you run `jar`? It could also explain why the size is so small.

Comment: Okay, i did not make any changes..now it says Exception in main thread, noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell your jar that where is your main class ,
see this link ,http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html